# SSL certificate for AWS internal load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, amazon-elb

We have an internal facing application load balancer in AWS VPC. This is being accessed by a web app running in a public subnet. The web app is behind a custom domain url and it uses SSL certificate for security.Since, the API load balancer is not applied with SSL, communication from web app to API LB is failing.

Is it possible to get a SSL certificate for an internal facing load balancer in AWS?

Comment: this might help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ssl-server-cert.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is entirely possible using the AWS ACM service, there are two options, you can use Amazon's public service to generate certs but I assume that is not what you want to do here.  So you can alternatively create a Private CA through this service and distribute your certificates from there which can then be placed on Loadbalancers etc.  You will most likely want to look at these pages:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-overview.html
https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/

Have a read first before diving right in but it's a pretty nifty feature for this sort of thing, once the CA is setup then creating certs is so fast and instantly attachable to resources.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually the customer went ahead with public facing ELB for APIs and SSL certificate is applied as AWS ACM was bit costly for the project

Comment: Yeah the first time setup cost is pretty steep, but if need a big scalable solution that isn't running a certificate signer on an EC2 instance then it's a good go to :) Happy to hear you got it sorted.